# Registry Key returns Null

Tags: .net, registry

```
 Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey( "SqlServerConnectionString", True)
    If key Is Nothing Then
        key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(RegistryKey)
    End If
    key.SetValue("SqlServerConnectionString", txtSqlServerConnectionString.Text)
```

i created 7 keys by this technic
finally  i tryed to retrieve data from the created registry key 
this way

```
        Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SqlServerConnectionString", False)
    txtSqlServerConnectionString.Text =key.GetValue( "SqlServerConnectionString", "")
```

i have 7  key  which is  created in registry 
only 2 of them does not work correctly and return null 
i hope this post be more clear

Comment: Is it just me or is this question not very clear?

Comment: Unfortunately, without seeing the code, all I can say is that you must be doing something wrong, but I gather you've figured that out already. Please rewrite your question, and post some code.

Comment: I took the liberty to rewrite most of it in current english, feel free to undo my changes if you feel I changed the meaning of the original question. I couldn't figure out by memory what `registrykey.setvalue()` was referring to, so i left it unchanged.

Comment: It would also be worth mentioning what types of values you're getting/setting.  Is it always string values that return null, where as numeric values work for example...